# Ethereum Wallet on Mac - Way Too Slow and uses up CPU!

Tags: synchronization

I am really concerned with the amount of blocks I have to sync and how long it takes/how much power it consumes. It took me 2-3 days to fully sync last week and now I am syncing all day again. It feels that with current volumes it won't be long before it will be mathematically impossible for me to sync.

I have seen some posts about fast geth (no idea what it is/what it means) but they give some programming codes and I have no idea what to do or where to start. I refuse to use an online wallet as this means trusting someone else (I have few hundred £ in cryptsy).

Is there anything like Electrum for ethereum where long block dl & sync is not required? Just wanted to also add that I am certain way more people would use ethereum and its price would rise if the interface was more user friendly and long sync wasn't required.

Update: checked for updates and running latest version of Ethereum (09/09/2017)

Comment: Do you know if your disk drive a solid state disk or a hard disk drive? Syncing is much slower on a mechanical hard disk drive. Also, you might like to try Parity instead of `geth`; I find it to be much faster.

Comment: Hello, thnx for the reply. I read this before and sorry forgot to mention I have a samsung SSD 1TB drive it's only a couple of years old so I can't imagine it's the problem =-/

Comment: How would I go about trying Parity?

Comment: The official Parity website is https://parity.io (you might want to confirm that I haven't made a mistake or that I'm running a racket) -- also https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/should-i-use-any-ethereum-wallet-listed-on-your-search-engine-or-advertisments (but you can see I've been involved in an edit). Make sure you have regular backups of your data. Also, if you install Parity after you have `geth`, Parity _should_ just pick up your old `geth` keys (it did for me, but that was pre-DAO, AKA a dog's age in Ethereum time).

Comment: I am somewhat concerned as when i try to run the installer it tells me it's an experiment and as per your link I am not sure how much I would trust parity, the wallet also has a low review when I checked via google. Also I am not sure what they mean by 'browser' =-S.

Comment: I think the "experimental" bit that's referring to the installer itself (as opposed to `cargo build; cargo run`). Parity has been around for a while and its usage shot up when there was an attack exploiting mis-priced EVM instructions (https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/55s085/geth_nodes_under_attack_again_we_are_actively/). Parity did suffer an exploit to their multisig wallet code a few months back -- perhaps that's what you saw. But I don't really keep up with the Joneses, so it's quite possible Parity's wallet isn't very good compared to other options.